# VS Code Typescript Auto Import does not use index.ts in React

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I am using [Auto Import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) in VS Code and it is working in some of my projects.

I also have a React project where Auto Import will not import from `index.ts`. It also does not show the option for the path to `index.ts` in the popup on <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>

How do I get Auto Import to add the path without the file name on the end, eg.

```
import { numRelays } from './../redux/reducer'
```

instead of

```
import { numRelays } from './../redux/reducer/relayReducer'
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

[image]